# Julia idiomatic way of catching exceptions except of interrupt?

Tags: julia, idioms

Quite often I process data in Julia and don't want it to crash it, so I use try-catch block. But I'm also debugging it in REPL and then I actually want to kill the block if I see it's doing something wrong.
So far my solution is

```
for i in <some big loop>
    try
        do_job(i)
    catch e
        e isa InterruptException && rethrow(e)
        @warn "job failed" i e
    end
end
```

but it does not feel very idiomatic. Is there something better?
I saw this 7 years old question https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/4037 but it still seems unsolved.

Comment: AFAICT this is the most idiomatic way to handle interrupts.

Comment: I see. I was looking for some more robust way, but I guess this is it. 
I checked the type hierarchy for Exception and `InterruptException` is just one of the many exception, so there is probably nothing better to be done I guess.

I guess I'll leave this question open for better ideas, but if this truly is the most idiomatic way, I could answer and close it.
idk